# Summing multiple rows on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Suppose I have the following table:

[image: (can't embed images yet)]

I'd like to find the total number of apples sold on day 1, regardless of customer sold to.

I'm somewhat familiar with `INDEX/MATCH` but I'm not too sure on how to proceed.

I understand that the `SUMIF` function can be used to sum only the desired day, but I am unsure of how to sum multiple rows with `INDEX/MATCH`.

The output I'm looking for is as follows:

[image: (can't embed this either)]

But most importantly, I'd like to know **how to sum multiple specific rows** and thus I'm requesting **a formula for B16**.

Comment: Does each day have fixed number of rows? In the image you've attached, it's six.

Comment: @Mahesh my bad, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the option of unmerging the cells in column A and normalizing it, then a simple `SUMIFS` should work. Otherwise, try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$13,
1*($B$2:$B$13=$A16),
1*(ROW($A$2:$A$13)>=SMALL(ROW($A$2:$A$13)+100*($A$2:$A$13=""),B$15)),
1*(ROW($A$2:$A$13)<SMALL(ROW($A$2:$A$13)+100*($A$2:$A$13=""),B$15+1)))
```

**Result:**

```
╔════════╦════╦════╗
║  Day   ║ 1  ║ 2  ║
╠════════╬════╬════╣
║ Apple  ║ 60 ║ 90 ║
║ Orange ║  0 ║ 85 ║
║ Pear   ║ 75 ║  0 ║
╚════════╩════╩════╝
```

**Source:**

Modified the formula [found here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3970-excel-find-nth-non-blank-cell.html):

**Explanation:**

The core part is the `SMALL` function

```
SMALL(ROW($A$2:$A$13)+100*($A$2:$A$13=""),B$15)
```

It creates an array of row numbers for a specified range, where cells not containing anything (`=""`) have a value that's 100 more than the corresponding row number (`+100*`). On the other hand, the cells failing the condition (i.e., non-blank cells) will only be assigned their row numbers. This array is passed on to the `SMALL` function with `B$15` as the second argument, which tells it to fetch the *kth* smallest item in the array.

So, we want to sum the rows where the row starts with the day number, which is what this part does:

```
1*(ROW($A$2:$A$13)>=SMALL(ROW($A$2:$A$13)+100*($A$2:$A$13=""),B$15))
```

However, we also want to restrict the totalling up to the cell directly above the next non-blank cell; hence, the `<` operator and `B$15+1` (i.e., *(k+1)th* smallest item) in the following part:

```
1*(ROW($A$2:$A$13)<SMALL(ROW($A$2:$A$13)+100*($A$2:$A$13=""),B$15+1))
```

Comment: Great solution when the merged cells are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you can unmerge the cells for your `Day` field, such that the day number appears in every row, a **Pivot Table** would be by far the easiest way to obtain the result you require:

[image: Pivot]

Comment: As @Mahesh mentioned, if the cells in column A can be unmerged, a simple [SUMIFS()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumifs-function) will work.  Fill this right and down from B16:  =SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,B$15,B:B,$A16).

Comment: @Bandersnatch IMO, a Pivot Table is a better solution since the `SUMIFS` expression would need to be modified for every new day added to the dataset, a Pivot Table would not.

Comment: Not really.  The summary table (see OP's expected output) would get a new column for each new day, and the formula gets the day number from the header.  I don't really like Pivot tables, mainly because I think they prevent new users from learning how to use formulas.  That said, I've been impressed with the quality and thoroughness of your answers outlining how to use them.

Comment: @Bandersnatch Thank you for your recognition, it makes the time invested constructing the answers all the more worthwhile. Maybe I'm a little biased, as I use Pivot Tables on a daily basis to offer end-users flexibility when viewing database extracts (with automatic refreshing of the content) and so I'm a huge fan of their functionality. Formulae certainly have their place, but I find that their overuse can lead to obfuscated spreadsheets which can become difficult to maintain. My 2p. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, column A is merged, but I appreciate your help nonetheless. I haven't used pivot tables before, but this has opened my eyes to them.